# ubuntu 16 with visual studio code locking every folder when its created

Tags: visual-studio-code, ubuntu-16.04, gatsby, brunch

I'm currently trying to get off of Windows and have started doing more Javascript development in visual studio code on a desktop setup running Ubuntu 16. Every time I'm building something with Angular or any modern JS framework where I'm creating components from the command line, it will lock those files or folders and tell me I don't have admin access and I have to continually unlock those files or folders every time I want to save my work.

I'm normally using Webpack or Brunch so I'm using the `--watch` function so when I make a change it will recompile and then refresh the browser with my changes.

I've used Nautilus to unlock the project folders, I've also used

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /path to folder
```

To try and unlock the files at the project folder level thinking by doing so any additional file or folder added therein would be unlocked, but its not working.

My question then is what do I have to do or settings can I change so this isn't an issue any more? I love my Linux setup and would hate to have to go back to Windows because of a minor permissions issue like this.

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Pete

Comment: What command are you using to creating the components? Make sure you're not using `sudo` at the start

Comment: In Angular, I use the ng generate to create components like:

ng generate service crypto

or with Brunch when you create a new project:

 brunch new proj -s es6